# Aplicativo android gerando a exception: androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException

Tags: android, kotlin

Meu aplicativo está em produção e eu estou com um problema em uma pequena parte dos dispositivos, ainda não consegui identificar o motivo ou ao menos reproduzir o problema em um ambiente de teste, realizei algumas pesquisas buscando mais informações, mas sem sucesso, gostaria que a comunidade me direcionasse para possíveis situações que podem está gerando esse problema.
O meu aplicativo é simples, é um aplicativo de notícias e quando possui noticias novas o aplicativo notifica os usuários.

Os dispositivos que apresentaram o erro:

1. Samsung Galaxy A20 (a20), 2816MB RAM, Android 9
2. Samsung Galaxy J4 (j4lte), 2048MB RAM, Android 9
3. Motorola Moto G (5th Gen) (cedric), 2048MB RAM, Android 8.1
4. Samsung Galaxy J4 Core (j4corelte), 1024MB RAM, Android 8.1

Como eu não sei quais são as partes do código que estão relacionadas o problema, não coloquei nenhuma uma classe especifica, porém se alguém quiser é só solicitar nos comentários, por exemplo eu acredito que esteja relacionado a notificação.

O erro foi capturado direto da google play console.

> **java.lang.RuntimeException:**
>
> at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
>   (ActivityThread.java:3121)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity
>   (ActivityThread.java:3264)   at
>   android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute
>   (LaunchActivityItem.java:78)   at
>   android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks
>   (TransactionExecutor.java:108)   at
>   android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute
>   (TransactionExecutor.java:68)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1955) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:214)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7078)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)   at
>   com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
>   (RuntimeInit.java:494)   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
>   (ZygoteInit.java:965)
>
> Caused by: **androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException:**
>
> at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate (Fragment.java:538)
>   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate
>   (FragmentContainer.java:57)   at
>   androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$6.instantiate
>   (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2851)   at
>   androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.instantiate
>   (FragmentState.java:85)   at
>   androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreSaveState
>   (FragmentManagerImpl.java:2488)   at
>   androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.restoreSaveState
>   (FragmentController.java:195)   at
>   androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate
>   (FragmentActivity.java:288)   at
>   androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate
>   (AppCompatActivity.java:106)   at xxx.xxxx.xxxxx.MainActivity.onCreate
>   (MainActivity.kt:70)   at android.app.Activity.performCreate
>   (Activity.java:7339)   at android.app.Activity.performCreate
>   (Activity.java:7330)   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate
>   (Instrumentation.java:1275)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity
>   (ActivityThread.java:3101)
>
> Caused by: **java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:**
>
> at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0 (Class.java:2328)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor (Class.java:1725)   at
>   androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate (Fragment.java:523)

Parte da classe para onde o problema aponta

**MainActivity.kt**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) // Linha 70
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        ...
}
```

Outras classes que podem está relacionadas com o problema

**PagerAdapter.kt**

```
class PagerAdapter(val fragmentActivity: FragmentActivity, private var lista: MutableList<Blog>) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentActivity) {


    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return lista.size+1
    }

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {

        return if(position<lista.size)
            Tab(lista[position])
        else
            OutraTab() // tab fixa no final

    }

}
```

**Tab.kt**

```
 class Tab(private val blog: Blog) : Fragment() {

        ...

        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab, container, false)

        ...


        }

}
```

**OutraTab.kt**

```
   class OutraTab : Fragment() {

        override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
            val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_outra, container, false)

        ...


        }

    }
```

**Obs.** OutraTab.kt é semelhante ao Tab.kt, só que sem o parâmetro **blog** ela contem conteúdo fixo.

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito ampla, você poderia discutir algo assim no meta (se não estou enganado). Aqui as perguntas precisam ser objetivas, descrevendo um problema de forma que seja respondido diretamente e não de forma argumentativa.

Comment: Entendo, sei que as informações que eu tenho são insuficientes para resolver, é essa talvez a dificuldade para resolver esse problema, eu ainda não consegui reproduzi esse erro em um ambiente de teste, eu ainda não sei qual o fluxo que gera esse erro, porém acredito que alguém aqui na comunidade pode identificar algum erro de fluxo ou de lógica.. hoje eu vou  realizar novos testes e depois vou postar alguns trechos do código

Comment: Tudo bem, esperamos detalhes para te ajudar e também, deixar respostas úteis para pessoas que futuramente tenham o mesmo problema.

Comment: O método [`androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#instantiate(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) foi depreciado.

Comment: @AugustoVasques é verdade estava utilizando no meu PagerAdapter o FragmentStatePagerAdapter que está depreciado, mudei para o FragmentStateAdapter, mudei também o ViewPager para ViewPager2 que estava também depreciado,  o Android Studio não me alertou sobre isso, como eu não conseguir reproduzir o erro no cenário de testes, eu mudei também uma parte do fluxo do meu app, pra ver se o erro vai persistir e agora estou colocando em produção e vou observar se o erro vai continuar. Essa depreciação pode ocasionar o erro relatado?

Comment: Acho que avançamos com relação a esse problema, a dúvida também era que o problema apontava para a linha 70 do MainActivity, a linha 70 é  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState), só que até então não tinha sentido, porém agora percebemos que tinha um problema na interface (ViewPager depreciado), geralmente quando se tem algum problema na interface essa é a linha que é apontada pelo erro, alguém me corrija se eu estiver equivocado..

Comment: @LSA " Essa depreciação pode ocasionar o erro relatado?". Não use métodos depreciados. O padrão é um só Android, mas cada fabricante implementa os endpoints da API segundo seu hardware e talvez, pode ser por um outro motivo qualquer, o fabricante para economizar, memória,  mão de obra ou tempo desenvolvimento com material obsoleto decida não implementar os métodos depreciados em determinadas versões do OS e por isso acontece do código funcionar em algumas marcas/modelos e em outros marcas/modelos não funcionar.

Comment: Ok, o app já está produção, vou aguardar até os próximos dias para ver se o problema foi resolvido, se foi eu vou postar aqui o que foi feito exatamente no código para que possa ajudar outras pessoas com o mesmo problema.

Comment: As referencias da classe R as vezes se perdem e ocasiona em problema do RunTime. Mas vendo o erro, parece estar relacionado ao dado de acesso que esta a instanciar e não esta conseguindo exibir na ActivityThread. Tentou um novo build da aplicação?
O aplicativo esta dando erro apenas nesses modelos citados?
Usa API de acesso para exibir a noticias?

Comment: Eu pensei que substituindo os componentes depreciados o problema estaria resolvido, porém o problema continua, nessa nova versão lançada teve um erro igual no dispositivo Motorola Moto G (5S) (montana) android 8.1, porém eu estou tendo outra dúvida e não sei os efeitos colateral desse tipo de implementação, eu vou ter que abrir outra pergunta para tirar essa dúvida e depois voltar aqui, se não vai fugir do tema. Eu observei também que outro aplicativo que eu gerencio possui o mesmo erro.

Comment: @Nellonidas eu fiz um novo build, mas o erro continua, esse erro ele acontece de vez em quando ainda não conseguir reproduzir em cenário de teste, eu só consigo ver que ainda não foi sanado com os relatórios de falhas do google, provavelmente ocorre em outros dispositivos também, as notícias são carregadas direto dos sites através da biblioteca Jsoup

Comment: Imagino que ainda não tenha resolvido o problema. Todos seus fragmentos possuem um construtor com 0 argumentos (construtor padrão)? Se não, o problema pode ser esse (e então posso elaborar uma resposta sobre)

Comment: @RafaelTavares, ainda não, mas estou buscando corrigir, só o Fragmento OutraTab que possui 0 argumentos no construtor padrão, eu atualizei a resposta e coloquei as classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Resumo

Seus fragmentos precisam de um construtor padrão (sem argumentos) para que o Android consiga recriá-los quando necessário (quando mudar a orientação do celular, por exemplo).

### Explicação

Quando ocorre alguma mudança de configuração no Android (como mudança na orientação de retrato pra paisagem, ou mudança de idioma), a sua Activity é recriada.

No processo de recriação, os Fragments que serão recriados terão uma chamada `Construtor()`, ou seja, o construtor sem argumentos. O fato de não ter esse construtor gera o seguinte erro (que você indicou):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0 (Class.java:2328) at java.lang.Class.getConstructor
```

De acordo com a [documentação sobre alterações de configuração](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) do Android:

> Algumas configurações de dispositivo podem mudar durante o tempo de execução, como orientação da tela, disponibilidade do teclado e ativação do modo de várias janelas. Quando ocorre uma alteração, o Android precisa reiniciar a execução de **Activity** (`onDestroy()` é chamado, seguido de `onCreate()`).
>
> O comportamento de reinício foi projetado para ajudar o aplicativo a se adaptar a novas configurações atualizando automaticamente o aplicativo com recursos alternativos que correspondam à configuração do dispositivo.

### Solução com o Padrão de Nova Instância (NewInstance)

Esse padrão permite que você passe argumentos para um fragmento sem precisar criar um construtor que não seja o padrão. O padrão existe tanto em **Java** quanto em **Kotlin**, mas abaixo explico o processo no **Kotlin**. Na [documentação de Fragments](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) esse padrão é utilizado.

1. Crie um método `novaInstancia` para instanciar seu Fragment;
2. Receba os argumentos necessários nesse método e passe para o `onCreate` através de `arguments`;
3. No método `onCreate`, armazene os valores como atributos da sua class Fragment.

**Código do fragmento:**

```
private const val ARG_MEU_ATRIBUTO = "meuAtributoId"

class MeuFragmento: Fragment() {
    private var meuAtributo: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            meuAtributo = it.getString(ARG_MEU_ATRIBUTO)
        }
    }

    companion object {
        fun novaInstancia(valorDoAtributo: String?) =
                MeuFragmento().apply {
                    arguments = Bundle().apply {
                        putString(ARG_MEU_ATRIBUTO, valorDoAtributo)
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

**Para instânciar seu fragmento:**

```
val meuFragmento = MeuFragmento.novaInstancia("texto")
```

### NewInstance com o Android Studio

Quando você for criar um fragmento novo, deixe a opção "*Include fragment factory methods?*" marcada e o código será gerado com o padrão descrito acima.

[image: Janela de criação de fragmento do Android Studio]

**Código gerado:**

```
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Use the [BlankFragment.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class BlankFragment : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false)
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment BlankFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
                BlankFragment().apply {
                    arguments = Bundle().apply {
                        putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                        putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                    }
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: Entendi, vou realizar as modificações no código e assim que eu verificar que o problema foi corrigido eu aceito a resposta como correta.

Comment: @LSA A resposta acima resolveu o seu problema? Precisa de ajuda com algo mais?

Comment: Aparentemente sim, porém preciso de mais uns 2 a três 3 dias para que a maior parte do usuários do aplicativo já esteja utilizando essa última versão, agora me responde, se possível, o fragmento precisa de um construtor vazio para recriado nesses cenários, porém o contexto fornece os argumentos que a situação pede automaticamente ?  ou se precisa-se recriar, o parâmetro  ARG_PARAM1 seria "param1", ou como no teu exemplo ARG_MEU_ATRIBUTO seria "meuAtributoId" ? Eu precisaria criar um valor "default" no lugar do "meuAtributoId" para quando isso ocorresse ?

Comment: Você não precisa indicar um valor padrão. Mesmo após o fragmento ser recriado, o `arguments` continua passando o valor do `novaInstancia` no `onCreate`. Você pode testar isso colocando um `Log.d()` para checar os valores passados

Comment: Perfeito, parece que o problema foi resolvido, cerca de 95% dos usuários estão utilizando o app agora e não tive mais relatos do google play com relação a esse problema.